# How to catch Access denied errors while using sqlalchemy library?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to catch the access denied errors while accessing mysql database using sqlalchemy, I can see the exception stack with exception being

`OperationalError(1045, "Access denied for user 'nova'@'172.18.9.200' (using password: YES)")`

but the exception object doesn't have a method to retrieve code or status to determine whether it is a access denied error, Other than matching exception string is there a better way to find out the access denied errors with this sqlalchemy exception?

There doesn't seem to be a method or variable or property to access the code.

`16         try:
 17             services = api.service_get_all(ctxt)
 18             print "Received objects: ", len(services)
 19         except sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError as ex:
 20             print dir(ex)
 21             if "Access denied" in str(ex):`

It shows no method to access it.

```
print dir(ex)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__',      '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', 'add_detail', 'args', 'connection_invalidated', 'detail', 'instance', 'message', 'orig', 'params', 'statement']

dir(ex.orig)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', 'args', 'message']
```

Comment: But it does have a code: 1045.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a method or variable or property to access the code. I edited my question

Comment: It depends on the driver. For MySQL-connector I believe it's available at `e.errno`. What driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`ex.message` is str of `ex.orig.args`; the mysql error code can be found in `err.orig.args[0]`.