# Identifying sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-db-api

I'm trying to catch mysql/sqlalchemy OperationalErrors and replace handle access denied (1045) differently from connection refused (2003)

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user … (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I just can't seem to find any documentation on how to tell these apart programmatically. I dived into the sources and thought I could check the value of err.orig.original_exception.errno but that was not the case.

Edit: err.orig doesn't seem to be defined for access denied which might be a bug.

```
try:
  engine.scalar(select([1]))
except sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError as err:
  if err_______:
    print("Access Denied")
  elifif err_______:
    print("Connection Refused")
  else:
    raise
```

Comment: Similar question from 2016 without an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39106138/3080094

Comment: How could I not find that, thank you so much!

Comment: have you tried `e.errno`? Reading this: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/6f270fb0e344016ce526e0a1ecb3e3de9ffd1e3b/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqlconnector.py#L233 I think OperationalErrors from `mysqlconnector.py` should have the property `errno` containing the error number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more research, I found the mysql error code to be in `err.orig.args[0]`. So the Answer is:

```
try:
  engine.scalar(select([1]))
except sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError as err:
  if err.orig.args[0]==1045:
    print("Access Denied")
  elif err.orig.args[0]==2003:
    print("Connection Refused")
  else:
    raise
```

Comment: Just a small typo in your example: `elifif`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `err.args[0]`

```
try:
  engine.scalar(select([1]))
except sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError as err:
  if err.args[0] == 1045:
    print("Access Denied")
  elif err.args[0] == 2003:
    print("Connection Refused")
  else:
    raise
```

This should be what you're looking for. Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) for more reading

**Edit**

As [OperationalError](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError) wraps [DBAPIError](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError), that has a `code` argument. Most likely just replace `args[0]` with `code`. Like so:

```
try:
  engine.scalar(select([1]))
except sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError as err:
  if err.code == 1045:
    print("Access Denied")
  elif err.code == 2003:
    print("Connection Refused")
  else:
    raise
```

Comment: args[0] is a string containing the above error messages. But comparing error message strings can't be the right solution here

Comment: This is a sqlalchemy code and only means operational error, which becomes obvious when looking at err.py

Comment: I've been at this for a while and it's much harder than it looks. I found out isinstance(err.orig.original_exception,ConnectionRefusedError) works for the connection refused case only. Otherwise orig is None apparently

Comment: I read a lot of source and documentation, the links aren't helping. I assume that I'm supposed to be looking at err.orig and the fact that that isn't defined for permission denied might be a bug I'll have to hack around – and end up comparing error message strings. I'll investigate further tomorrow, until that, I hope someone familiar with this looks into it.

Comment: I hope you find your answer, I'm not proficient with SQLAlchemy